# Jetpack Compose FAB hide on scroll behavior

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

In the XML-based UI, FAB had a field to override the custom scroll behavior. Since there is no such parameter in the function in Compose FAB implementation, it became a little unclear how to implement the hide on scroll behavior.

I use Scaffold with the `nestedScroll` modifier in order for my СollapsingAppBar to work. I assumed at first that it was necessary to create an object inherited from the `NestedScrollConnection` interface. And also connect it with the `nestedScroll` modifier to Scaffold. But unfortunately, as I understand it, it is impossible to connect several `scrollBehavior` objects to one Scaffold at once.

```
val scrollBehavior = TopAppBarScrollBehavior()
val scrollBehavior1 = FloatingActionButtonScrollBehavior()

Scaffold(
    modifier = Modifier
        .nestedScroll(scrollBehavior.nestedScrollConnection)
        //this one won't work
        .nestedScroll(scrollBehavior1.nestedScrollConnection)
        ...
```

Comment: can you share `TopAppBarScrollBehavior` code and `FloatingActionButtonScrollBehavior` code too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If someone is interested in how to implement this behavior, I found this solution:

```
@Composable
fun AnimatedFloatingActionButton(
    ...
    listState: LazyListState
) {
    AnimatedVisibility(
        visible = listState.isScrollingUp().value,
        enter = //TODO: your enter animation,
        exit = //TODO: your exit animation
    ) {
        FloatingActionButton(
            ...
        )
    }
}
```

You only need to create a `LazyListState` inside your Composable parent, and pass it inside the `AnimatedFloatingActionButton`. And also define an extension function for `LazyListState`.

```
@Composable
fun LazyListState.isScrollingUp(): State<Boolean> {
    return produceState(initialValue = true) {
        var lastIndex = 0
        var lastScroll = Int.MAX_VALUE
        snapshotFlow {
            firstVisibleItemIndex to firstVisibleItemScrollOffset
        }.collect { (currentIndex, currentScroll) ->
            if (currentIndex != lastIndex || currentScroll != lastScroll) {
                value = currentIndex < lastIndex ||
                        (currentIndex == lastIndex && currentScroll < lastScroll)
                lastIndex = currentIndex
                lastScroll = currentScroll
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: remove lastIndex = currentIndex if you want to show when scrolling to the top.

Answer (score 1):

According to `nestedScroll` [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/input/nestedscroll/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).nestedScroll(androidx.compose.ui.input.nestedscroll.NestedScrollConnection,androidx.compose.ui.input.nestedscroll.NestedScrollDispatcher)) it takes 2 arguments

```
fun Modifier.nestedScroll(
  connection: NestedScrollConnection,
  dispatcher: NestedScrollDispatcher? = null
): Modifier
```

`NestedScrollDispatcher` is needed if a component is able to receive and react to the drag/fling events. I think you have to implement `NestedScrollDispatcher` to coordinate FAB's visibility with scroll.

Comment: Can you give a small example of an implementation?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a similar implementation but a bit easier, so to do this, you just need to track the state of a `LazyColumn` and check if you are seeing the first element, for example:

```
val listState = rememberLazyListState()
val isScrolledOnTop by remember { 
    derivedStateOf { listState.firstVisibleItemIndex == 0 } 
}
```

You can also check if you are at the top using:

```
val isScrolledOnTop by remember { 
    derivedStateOf { listState.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset == 0 } 
}
```

Then you can create the scaffold like this:

```
Scaffold(
    floatingActionButton = {
        ExtendedFloatingActionButton(
            onClick = {
               ...
            }
        ) {
            AnimatedVisibility(visible = isScrolledOnTop) {
                Text("Add")
            }
            Icon(Icons.Filled.Add, "Description")
        }
    },
) { 
    ScreenContent(   
        listState = listState
    )
 }
```

Finally, your `ScreenContent` needs a LazyColumn like this:

```
@Composable
fun ScreenContent(
    listState: LazyListState
){
     LazyColumn(state = listState) {
         ... 
     }
}
```